# Magento 2 remove home link from breadcrumb

Tags: magento2

We need to remove home link from breadcrumb from all pages.

Comment: See -- http://awesomescreenshot.com/06365aqvbd

Comment: You might have a theme level configuration in magento admin to remove Home link in navigation.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your reply
I found solutions regarding this
Go to Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/breadcrumbs.phtml

And add this line

```
<?php foreach ($crumbs as $crumbName => $crumbInfo) : ?>
        <?php if($crumbName == 'home') continue; ?> -- Add this line
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove breadcrumb links, you just need to remove the home page link from the breadcrumbs XML.

The tag of the XML should look like:

```
<item name="link" xsi:type="string">{{baseUrl}}</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below condition in `breadcrumbs.phtml` just before `<li>` tag.

```
<?php if($crumbName != 'home') : ?>
    <li></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```